# Why does the Central Limit Theorem have data tend towards a Normal Model?

Tags: statistics

There are many functions that "look" like the normal model (which is $e^{-x^2}$) such as $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ or $\operatorname{sech(x)}$. Why doesn't the Central Limit Theorem tend towards these functions? Why does it always tend toward the normal model?

Comment: Answers appear many places online, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: Well, it's going to have to go to something which gives finite variance, so your $1/(x^2+1)$ example doesn't decay fast enough (though $1/(x^4+1)$ for instance does decay fast enough for this requirement). As for otherwise, I think the proof using characteristic functions is fairly clear, even though it's not 100% general.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to intuitively see the Gaussian pop out (I don't claim any rigor). Consider a probability distribution $\psi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_{\geq0}$ with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\mathcal F$ denote the Fourier transform. Note that
$$
  (\mathcal F\psi)(0)=\int_{\mathbb R}\psi(x)\;dx=1,
$$
$$
  (\mathcal F\psi)'(0)=\int_{\mathbb R}ix\psi(x)\;dx=0,
$$
$$
  (\mathcal F\psi)''(0)=\int_{\mathbb R}-x^2\psi(x)\;dx=-\sigma^2.
$$
Thus $(\mathcal F\psi)(t)=1-\sigma^2t^2/2+O(t^3)$. Now draw $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ independently from $\psi$ and let $\psi_n$ denote the probability distribution of $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/\sqrt n$. Then
$$
  \psi_n(x)=\sqrt n(\psi*\psi*\ldots*\psi)(x\sqrt n)
$$
where $*$ denotes convolution. Thus
$$
  (\mathcal F\psi_n)(t)=((\mathcal F\psi)(t/\sqrt n))^n
    \approx\left(1-\sigma^2t^2/(2n)\right)^n
    \approx\exp(-\sigma^2t^2/2).
$$
Taking the inverse Fourier transform gives the expected result.

Comment: You have a missed minus sign and also a missed division sign.

Comment: @Ian thanks for catching those!